# PHP OAuth fetch() under CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, oauth

I'm creating a project which uses CakePHP framework, and the PHP OAuth module.

The reason I'm using the module over a Vendor plugin is because the APIs need to have data/custom headers sent to them or else they generate 500s, and I know the standard PHP module does this well.

The issue is that when I use OAuth->fetch("http://www.example.com" ...), CakePHP redirects the external fetch request to my localhost (which I'm developing on), thus resulting in no data being generated.

It looks like the only way I can get external data is by using CakePHP's HTTPSocket class, but that doesn't allow me to send that data I need to send to the OAuth provider.

Does anyone know how to turn off this routing, or if I should be doing something differently?

**UPDATE : Currently code is as follows:**

```
public function createClient() {
    $client = new OAuth(
        'key',
        'secret'
    );

    $client->disableSSLChecks();
    if ($accessToken = $this->getAccessToken() !== false) {
        $client->setToken(
            $accessToken[$this->accessTokenKeyKeyname],
            $accessToken[$this->accessTokenSecretKeyname]
        );
    }

    return $client;
}

$url = 'http://example.com';
$client = $this->createClient();
$client->fetch($url, null, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET);
```

The request/access tokens are generated successfully, but the fetch continues to redirect to localhost, instead of example.com (example.com being used as an example URL).

Comment: This sounds more like an PHP/Server thing... how should CakePHP interfer an HTTP reqeuest issued by an PHP module? Have you tried using `OAuth` outside of CakePHP to see if there's actually a difference?

Comment: @ndm On the same server/setup, outside of the CakePHP framework the requests are going through successfully. Within the framework I get an error saying the URL doesn't exist, and I see that the URL has been re-written to go to localhost.

Comment: I've just tested it on Windows with PHP 5.4.1, OAuth 1.2.3, CakePHP 2.2.3, and it's working fine for me. What versions are you using? And have you checked `OAuth::debugInfo` (needs `OAuth::enableDebug()` called), is there anything suspicious? Also does this happen with a clean default CakePHP installation too? And can you post your exact code (with possible credentials replaced of course)?

Comment: @ndm I've updated the post with the code that doesn't work, thanks for your help.

Comment: That answers 1 of my 4 questions :) I don't know what `$this->getAccessToken()` is doing, but assuming the access token is correct `fetch()` works fine for me with your code...